# Are pumpkin sprouts edible?

Tags: pumpkin

While pumpkin flowers are common in some gastronomical cultures, are edible the sprouts of pumpkin? I've cooked the sprouts (the first two leafs) of melon, which are close relatives, and it's delicious.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might be. According to [The Self Nutrition Data](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2598/2) (© Condé Nast):

`This food is very low in Cholesterol. It is also a good source of Calcium, and a very good source of Protein, Vitamin A, Vitamin C, Thiamin, Riboflavin, Niacin, Vitamin B6, Folate, Iron, Magnesium, Phosphorus, Potassium, Copper and Manganese.`

And there are [proposed ways](http://www.elperfecto.com/2010/06/23/can-you-eat-pumpkin-leaves/) to cook them.